# Redux dispatch inside Meteor Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink

Tags: reactjs, meteor, redux, react-redux

Is there a way to use `this.props.dispatch` of the redux store inside Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink ?

I am using React and React-redux inside a Meteor app.
Upon email verification i would like to send data through `this.props.dispatch`

I'm trying to make this work(if it is even possible):

```
Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink(function(token, done){
  console.log('onEmailVerificationLink token', token)
  console.log('this',this)
  var outerthis = this
  Accounts.verifyEmail(token, function(error){

    if(R.isNil(error)){


    }else{
      console.log('error of verifyEmail', error)
      outerthis.props.dispatch(changemainmessage(error.reason))
    }

  })

  done()
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import your store object from wherever it is defined

`import store from '../config/store'`

Then you can dispatch an action directly from the store object

`store.dispatch(changemainmessage(error.reason));`

[Read more here](https://redux.js.org/api/store#store-methods)

Also, I'd recommend using camelCase for your variables - it's way more readable and follows JavaScript convention

So `changemainmessage()` would be `changeMainMessage()`